# Base system driver error - HP Pavilion Entertainment PC dv9323cl

Tags: windows-7, drivers, video

I upgraded to Windows 7 and have a problem with my Nvidia GeForce Go 7600 not displaying properly. Also the Base System Drivers have yellow flags near them and it states that `The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28) There is no driver selected for the device information set or element. To find a driver for this device, click Update Driver`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix these issues?

Comment: You mean a dv9233cl?

Comment: HP Windows 7 upgrade guide.  http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Windows-7-Upgrade-Guide-for-dv6000-dv9000-models/td-p/179816

Answer (score 1):

The Base System Device is most likely your **[memory card reader](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-75937-1&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=ie&lang=en&os=4062&product=3925170)**.

Get the latest GeForce Go 7600 drivers from nVidia (**[32-bit](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_notebook_winvista_win7_179.48_beta.html)** or **[64-bit](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_notebook_winvista_win7_64bit_179.48_beta.html)**)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some problems sometimes in getting the GFX driver of an embedded or oanbard card working, even form the vendor.. Especially on 64bit or other operating systems.

I used to look at this website that offers optimise and opened graphics drivers that seem to work.. does require a bit of brute force sometimes - but generally no other site like this exists. http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/

Also make sure to install Power management drivers and the board chip set, those packages sometimes unlock other devices that are used with by common bus.

Answer (score 0):

Post the hardware IDs of the base system drivers and we can look around for you. You may also want to visit the nVidia site and run their graphics driver detection tool, and let it install the right display drivers for you.